# SQL statement join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stumped on creating a SQL server query.   I have two tables shown below with a one to many relationship.  I want to pull **all** activities and include the child pictures if/where `IsPrimary = true`.

```
SELECT dbo.Activity.ID, dbo.Activity.Details, dbo.ActivityPicture.DateUploaded, dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture, dbo.ActivityPicture.ImageData
FROM dbo.ReportTask 
INNER JOIN dbo.ActivityPicture ON dbo.Activity.ID = dbo.ActivityPicture .ActivityID AND dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture = 'true'
```

**Activity**
-ID
-Details

**ActivityPicture**
-ImageLocation
-Description
-DateUploaded
-IsPrimary
-ActivityID

Comment: You have 2 tables, but none of them is `dbo.ReportTask`

Comment: We need more ifnormation to answer this question.  Is `dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture` really a char/varchar/nvarchar?  Why are you selecting from ReportTask?  What's the relationship between Activity and ActivityPicture?  1..*, 0..*, 0..1, 1..1?

Comment: Is the column name `dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture` or `dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimary` (You have it both ways in your post)

Comment: I changed the table names and fields to simplify the question. I failed to change one of the table names in the query.  ReportTask = Activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  This will return all items from the first table regardless of whether they have child items in the 2nd table.

Comment: We really don't have enough information to know if this is the problem or not, and there are other problems with the query as written that this wouldn't address.

Comment: @DanField Actually it seems to be the right answer, don't know what other information would be really relevant

Comment: What is dbo.ReportTask?  Why isn't he querying dbo.Activity?  Is the relationship between Activity and ActivityPicture 0..1/* or is it 1..1/* (if so, then a LEFT JOIN isn't necessary).  Waht's the datatype of IsPrimaryPicture?  Is the column name actually IsPrimaryPicture or IsPrimary?

Comment: @DanField I asked about that too, but from the question body and the columns used on the join, it's pretty clear that `ReportTask` is `Activity`. And from the question: ` I have two tables shown below with a one to many relationship`.

Comment: If they're one to many he shouldn't need a LEFT JOIN.  And the question would still be are they still one to many when checking for `IsPrimary`

Comment: @DanField I think you're reading into this too much.  You're speculating on things that weren't specified by OP.  Sounds to me like he's using an `INNER` when he really wants a `LEFT`.  Give OP a chance to respond.

Comment: I apologize, I did a horrible job converting my real code into a simplified version of it.  A LEFT OUTER JOIN solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.Activity.ID, dbo.Activity.Details, dbo.ActivityPicture.DateUploaded, dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture, dbo.ActivityPicture.ImageData FROM dbo.ReportTask LEFT JOIN dbo.ActivityPicture ON dbo.Activity.ID = dbo.ActivityPicture .ActivityID AND dbo.ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture = 'true'
```

That will return all the actives and include the ActivityPicture.IsPrimaryPicture where true.